# Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)| \leq M$ for all $z$ such that $|z| = R$.

Tags: complex-analysis

a) Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)| \leq M$ for all $z$ such that $|z| = R$. Show that $$|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq \dfrac{n!M}{R^{n}}~~,n = 1,2,3,... $$

b) Deduce from (a) that if $a_j \in \mathbb{C}$ and the polynomial $$P(z) = a_0 + a_1z + ...+ a_n z^{n}$$
satisfies $$|P(z)| \leq 1$$
for $|z| =1 $, then for $0 \leq j \leq n$, $$|a_j| \leq 1$$

c) Deduce from (b) that for $|z| \geq 1$,$$|P(z)| \leq |z|^{n}$$

This was a past year exam question, for part a), it merely is Cauchy's inequality. Part b is just using Cauchy integral formula and one should show that $a_j = \dfrac{P^{j}(0)}{j!}$ to do.

However, i cannot understand part c at all and do not see the link whatsoever with part b.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set
$$g(z) = \frac{P(z)}{z^n}.$$
Choose $R > 0$ such that
$$\vert g(z) \vert < \vert a_n \vert + \epsilon$$
when $\vert z \vert \geq R$. If $P(z) = z^n$, then (c) is obvious. If not, then $\vert P(z) \vert < 1$ on some arc of the unit disk. We can then obtain the strict inequality $\vert a_n \vert < 1$. Therefore
$$\vert g(z) \vert < 1$$
when $\vert z \vert \geq R$ if $\epsilon$ is chosen sufficiently small.

By the maximum modulus principle, the maximum of $g$ on annulus $1 \leq \vert z \vert \leq R$ must occur on the boundary. Since $\vert g(z) \vert < 1$ when $\vert z \vert \geq R$, the maximum must occur on the unit disk $\vert z \vert = 1$. But $\vert g(z) \vert < 1$ when $\vert z \vert = 1$, thus $\vert g(z) \vert \leq 1$ holds on the whole annulus. Therefore $\vert g(z) \vert \leq 1$ whenever $\vert z \vert \geq 1$.